# Calculation with vectors from box2d causes lagg

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, box2d

I am trying to implement Artificial intelligence in my actionScript3 game using vectors from box2d. I am copying vector, multiplying, normalizing ...  10 times each update and because of so much calculations game starts to lagg. How do i reduce that lagg, bescause game almost freezes. Is that a bug or i am not doing it right.

```
    var velocityTemp:b2Vec2 = velocity.Copy();
                    velocityTemp.Normalize();
                    var forward:b2Vec2 = b2Vec2.Make(velocityTemp.x, velocityTemp.y);
                    var diff:b2Vec2 = b2Vec2.Make(obstacles[i].getPosition().Copy().x - position.x,obstacles[i].getPosition().Copy().y - position.y);
                    var dotProduct:Number = b2Math.Dot(diff, forward);
velocityTemp = null;
            velocity = null;
            position = null;
            forward = null;
            diff = null;
            dotProduct = 0;
```

I tried setting them all to null but problem still exist.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is your bottleneck?

Comment: if i comment those lines game is working fine, if i write just vector.normalize() game slowly starts to lagging, so i think this is a problem.

Comment: Any calculations with vector will cause fps drop, Any ideas?